# Bash how to print next element of command line argument

Tags: bash

I have one script which takes command line 6 inputs

TestScript.sh  arg1 arg1out arg2 arg2out arg3 arg3out

so I am using for loop to check the argument name since sequence  can change

and I want argument next to it to be used as value

```
for i; do 
if [ "$i" == "arg1" ]
then

  if [ -z "$2" ] 
     then echo "Wrokspace cancatination is empty"
     else ws_concatination=$2
     echo $ws_concatination
     fi
elif [ "$i" == "arg3" ] 
then
  if [ -z "$2" ] 
     then echo "provide poddeffilepath "
     else poddef_path=$2
     echo $file
     fi
elif [ "$i" == "arg5" ] 
then
  if [ -z "$2" ] 
    then echo "provide productname "
    else product=$2
    echo $product
    fi

fi

done
```

so here instead of using $2 I want to take next value of "i" which means if 
`"$i" == "arg1"` then `ws_concatination will be`arg1out```  means i+1 th element in java

is it possible to do it in bash 
please help...

Comment: You need this `for i in "$@"; { ...; }`

Comment: Replace `for i` with `while (($#)); do i=$1` and `shift` arguments after parsing them.

Comment: [getopts](https://sookocheff.com/post/bash/parsing-bash-script-arguments-with-shopts/) is your friend.